# Как получить результат из JavascriptExecutor.executeScript()?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Для загрузки страницы c Selenium используется вот такой код:

```
String url = ...
executeScript(format("window.location.href='%s'", url))
```

Метод `executeScript` возвращает `Object`. Возможно ли получить в качестве результата `boolean` удалось ли успешно загрузить страницу или нет? И если да то как? А если нет то, каким образом можно организовать такую проверку?

Comment: вам не [это](https://www.testingexcellence.com/webdriver-wait-page-load-example-java/) нужно?

Comment: @TimurVI не совсем, там неудачная загрузка рассматриватся как ошибка, а в контексте моей бизнес логики эта ситуация не рассматривается как проблема. Не загрузилось и ладно идем дальше. Я для этого и перешел с метода get(url) на js вариант чтобы иметь возможность получить ответ есть страница или нет и продолжить выполнение в случае чего по тому сценарию где данная страница отсутствует.

Comment: Если нужно просто проверить есть ли страница, то лучше сделать это `HTTP`  `GET` запросом. Если вернется `200`, то все ок